# WinRT Store Apps 30% to 100% view

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

So right now I have an app that displays a menu when its in 30% mode, and when you click a button on the menu a popup informs you that it needs to switch to a full view in order to display the page the user selected, to do this it offers a Full Screen button and a Cancel button. If the user clicks the full screen button it should then snap the app out of 30% mode into full screen. To do this I am using the     windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.TryUnsnap(); API call. However, when I make this call it only changes the App to 70% mode. I can't find any documentation anywhere that says Apps can't go to 100% but at the same time the only API ever mentioned is the TryUnsnap(); and its doc's say nothing about %screen it can go to.

Can someone tell me if there is a way to go from 30% to 100% in WinRT store apps, or a MS doc that says 70% is the limit?

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible at this time. It's really up to the user - since they were in snap mode, Windows wants them to stay in snap mode.